# "Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable' was thrown" when resuming after long time in Background

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, crash

I developped an application that do multiple things like gps tracking etc . For the app, I'm actually using fragments.

I recently discovered that If I let the applicaiton a long time in the background, the app restart and then the fragment are overlapping. I found then a topic that suggets me so check is there is a savedInstancedState before calling the function that recreate the fragments and then cause the overlapping situaiton, so in On create: I check with a simple if so I create the fragments only if it's null .

```
  if (bundle == null)
        {
```

Testing the app again, the fragments doesn't overlapp anymore but after a long time in background, when I resume it. The application crash. I added then some code to catch the exception and the result is the following :

```
Time: 14-06-18 09:40:26
Error: Unhandled Exception
System.Exception: CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException ---> Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: Exception of type 'Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable' was thrown.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I just looked for some topic for my problem but I didn't find any answers that suit my problem.

Do you guys got any suggestion for me ?

Comment: Could you tell us what have you tried? Or how can I reproduce your problem?

Comment: Well, I just let it as it was. I didn't worked on it anymore. To reproduce the problem, you only have to set up like three fragments that you make visible or not depending on a menu. When the app with theses fragments goes into background for a too long time, the application crash, I don't have more informations about it :/.